# Mark a rails TestUnit test as a TODO?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, testunit

Is there a way to basically mark a TestUnit test as a "todo"? I thought I could do it by using `pending` at the top of the test, but that still runs the test (and thus it's red). I'd like to basically do the same thing, but not actually run the test (just skip over it).

Does anybody know of a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, do you *want* the test to show up as red but just not run the code, or do you want that pending tests should not even show up as red? (`pending` will show up as red because it is a constant reminder that the test is not yet implemented/completed. To sidestep that would mean that you have to remember that you marked some tests as "TODO", even using the technique mentioned by Chris.)

Comment: yeah, that's why you need a puts statement in the body of the test so that you'll see the todo message when you run the test. usually go with "TODO add assertions to NameOfTest.test_method" you can also keep a counter as an instance variable and increment it inside the test, then show the total of TODO's at the end of the test run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if these are test case stubs, you could just put assert true as the only assertion and a puts in the test to describe what needs to be done. this of course wouldn't help if your tests have failing assertions unless you comment them out.